# NSUserDefaultsで保存した小数をツイートする方法

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

クリアまでのタイムを競うゲームでタイムを小数点２桁で表示しているのですが、そのタイムをNSUserDefaultsで保存して結果画面で表示させるまではできました。しかし、保存したタイムをツイートしようとしたら小数点の桁数が正確に出てしまい困っています。

```
let str = "".stringByAppendingFormat("%.2f",cnt)
time1.text = str
```

このコードで小数点を２桁にしていて

```
func onPostToTwitter1(sender : AnyObject) {

    let ud1 = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let cnt = ud1.floatForKey("time")　//cntは少数で表示したいタイムです。

    myComposeView1 = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)


    myComposeView1.setInitialText(" ただいまのタイムは \(cnt)秒です。 " )

    self.presentViewController(myComposeView1, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

このコードでツイートを有効にしているのですがこのコードの中に小数点２桁にするコードを書いたらエラーが出ました。

簡単に今回の質問の内容をまとめますと、保存した小数点２桁のタイムがツイートするときは正確に出すぎて（２桁以上）困っているということです。

説明がわかりにくくてゴメンなさい。
ご回答お待ちしています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode 7、Swift 2.0を前提にして説明します。

```
let str = "".stringByAppendingFormat("%.2f",cnt)
time1.text = str
```

`String`型で、`NSString`のたくさんのメソッドがそのまま使えるようになりました。

```
let str = String(format: "%.2f", cnt)
```

こういうイニシアライザが使えます。

```
myComposeView1.setInitialText(" ただいまのタイムは \(cnt)秒です。 " )
```

これも、

```
let theText = String(format: " ただいまのタイムは %.2f秒です。", cnt)
myComposeView1.setInitialText(theText)
```

とすれば、小数点以下2桁で表示できます。

※`NSUserDefaults`に、いちいち浮動小数点数に変換しないで、Stringのまま保存していいんじゃないかという疑問は残りますけど……